# wait image does not work with all ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code to show the wait image for every ajax call. It works to some limit. What I mean by this is that it works for all ajax calls except ajax.beginform.

I did a test by adding specific ajax call on the same view and the wait image shows up (see 3rd code block below). However, when I submit the ajax form, it doesn't show up.

I also tried adding LoadingElementId = "waitImageDiv" to ajax.beginform as an alternative solution and that didn't work either.

I'm not sure why it works with all ajax calls except for ajax.beginform. Am I missing something? I make sure I have unobtrusive.js loaded as well.

_layout script:

```
$('#waitImageDiv').hide();
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('#waitImageDiv').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#waitImageDiv').hide();
});
```

XYZ_View div:

```
<div id="waitImageDiv" style="display:none"><img src="~/Content/images/PleaseWait.gif" /></div>
```

XYZ_View form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Report", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{ ....  }
```

XYZ_View js:

```
   $("#drpList").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: ...,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'Json',
                data: ... ,
                success: ....
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Shame on me for not checking unobtrusive carefully. I was just checking view source for -data tag and a script path with the word "unobtrusive.js". Apparently that is not good enough. I had jquery.validate.unotrusive.js not jquery.unotrusive-ajax.js.